# Seem to bought the ideas

Tags: adjectives

> They seem to bought the ideas from the crooked politician.

I believe I have heard the use of "seem to bought" in movies before, but is it grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's incorrect.

It should read:

"They seem to **have** bought the ideas from the crooked politician."

Although "of the crooked politician" sounds more idiomatic.

Comment: +1, but I think replacing ‘from’ with ‘of’ changes the meaning subtly, although I can’t figure out quite how.